# Count distinct MongoDb from array of values

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have an array of distinct items -

```
search = alluk.distinct('Object of search')
```

I am looking to do a count for each item. Currently I am doing them manually like so -

```
alluk.find({'Object of search':'Offensive weapons'}).count()
```

**Question**

Is it possible to loop through the search array counting for each item in turn?

I have tried -

```
alluk.find({'Object of search':{'$in': search}}).count()
```

However this isn't exactly what I am after.

**SOLUTION -**

```
for item in alluk.aggregate([
  { '$match': { 'Object of search': { '$in': objectofsearch }}},
  { '$group': {
    '_id': '$Object of search',
    'count': { '$sum': 1 }
  }}
]):
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) aggregation to count the number of distinct counts

```
alluk.aggregate([
  { '$match': { 'Object of search': { '$in': search }}},
  { '$group': {
    '_id': '$Object of search',
    'count': { '$sum': 1 }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks final solution added